# Fetching data from an online MySQL DB using Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

My question is really straightforward, is there any way of fetching data from a remote MySQL database without the need for a PHP script?
Is there any way that can be done with drivers like ODBC or something?
I'm not looking for any tutorial, i've found several. I just want a straightforward answer!

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use PHP. That is just one of many approaches to this problem.

I personally would use a service-oriented architecture (SOA). This means you will need a web service client (your mobile application), a web service, and a database. Your application will interact with the database using the webservice.

I would create a web-service using something like J2EE that receives a request from the locally installed android application, and responds with the required data from the external MySql database.

I would also use theKSOAP for android libraries to do this, but you should ideally be using REST.

Comment: +1 this is what i would do too. so far is the best approach i've tried.